# Problem with running Python script in AMBER suite environment

Tags: python

How to run a python script (which import numpy module) in AMBER suite environment using pbs script file?

A simple python script (which did not import numpy module) is running fine using `qsub` of the pbs script file.

I am giving python path like:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/scf-data/software/AMBER/amber18_intel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py
```

but it gives error as

```
raise ImportError("Unable to load the necessary modules")
ImportError: Unable to load the necessary modules.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `AMBER suite environment`? Even google doesnt know it...